# Android WebView does not shows a part of website

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to create a WebView application for https://nexchange.io. In the website there is a receive panel which shows the rate of ETH.

Whereas in the webview the rate does not show up. It works well in mobile browsers: [Image of the WebView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHtRQ.jpg)

Here is my WebView Code:

```
final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementById('header').style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementById('mouse-scroll').style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementById('recent-orders').style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementById('testimonials').style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementById('compare').style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementById('about').style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementById('subscription-form').style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                    "})()");
        }
    });
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://nexchange.io/");
```

Comment: posting your webview code might be helpful

Comment: Added the WebView Code if it may help.

Comment: You mean that code that you have works in a browser but not in webview?

Comment: The website opens up correctly in browser but not inside the webview

Comment: @Aniket I mean the code you have does it the same? Does it hide the stuff in the browser to?

Comment: No it does not hides in the browser